# Do I need to put the entity back into the repository after an update?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I read again the chapter on repositories in Evans' book and I am not yet clear on the following issue:

When I make modifications to an entity I got from a repository, do I need to put the entity back into the repository? Does the repository have any knowledge of the entities it reconstituted? (It seems obvious that if I did not modify the entity I retrieved from the repository, there is no need to add the entity back to it)

Thanks

Comment: I know it's almost a year old, but I wanted to add a paraphrase/snippet from the book "Domain Driven Design: Tackling complexity in the heart of software" by Eric Evans: repositories act as an in-memory collection of aggregates and thereby encapsulate the storage mechanism. [/end paraphrase] In-memory collections work one of two ways: they give out values and you have to update the collection with any change you make to the value, or they give out references and are already aware of changes you made. You will still have to tell the collection it needs to persist one way or another, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sure have a Save() method on your repository but for a nice separation of concerns, I find it better to handle change tracking and persistence in a Unit of Work. Most ORMs will allow you to save all modified entities that are part of a business transaction at once, or individual entities on an ad-hoc basis.

See http://richarddingwall.name/2009/10/22/repositories-dont-have-save-methods/

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2010/06/13/repositories-and-the-save-method.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The repository usually contains an interface containing methods such as Save, Update, and Delete.  So, yes, the client (domain layer) will typically "put the entity back" into the repository by invoking those methods on the repository.

If your domain code knows, in a given path, that no changes will be made, then it certainly would not need to call the update/save method again.  However, if you are unsure, it may make sense to invoke those methods and let the repository decide how (or whether) to update the underlying data store.

There are different ways to implement the repository and its interaction with the underlying data access layer and data store.  In theory, you could implement this with any approach you decide works best.  For example, the repository *could* query the data store and perform a comparison and look for changes as well.  However, in practice, many implementations use data tracking on the entity (e.g. IsDirty() or isModified()) to assist the repository in knowing whether the entity was changed by the domain layer and whether updates are necessary.

Hope this helps provide some direction.